# How do you find if a value is found in specific columns?

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse, dplyr

```
ID Pred1    Pred2   Pred3   Obs1    Obs2    Obs3   FP
1  Boston   Tokyo   London  Boston  London  Other  0
2  Tokyo    London  Paris   Seattle Paris   Other  0
3  London   Berlin  Paris   Paris   Berlin  London 0
4  Seattle  Berlin  London  Tokyo   Paris   Boston 1
```

This is my dataset. What I am trying to do is if any city ,that is at least one city, from predicted columns ('Pred1' 'Pred2', 'Pred3') is found in any of the observed columns (Obs1, Obs2, Obs3), then I give 0 to a column named fp. 
If nothing from the predicted column is found in the observed column, then I give 1 to the fp column.
I am trying

```
mutate(fp = ifelse(c(pred1, pred2, pred3) %in% c(obs1, obs2, obs3),0,1)
```

etc but Im not getting what I want...can anyone help? 
I would like to know how I can do this by using the `mutate` function with `'%in%'` specifically or any other methods if this doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a rowwise operation?

Comment: @Croote yes it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution with `apply` would be to check rowwise if any of the `"Pred"` columns has values present in `"Obs"` columns.

```
pred_cols <- grep("^Pred", names(df), value = TRUE)
obs_cols <- grep("^Obs", names(df), value = TRUE)

df$FP <- +(!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x[pred_cols] %in% x[obs_cols])))
df


#  ID   Pred1  Pred2  Pred3    Obs1   Obs2   Obs3 FP
#1  1  Boston  Tokyo London  Boston London  Other  0
#2  2   Tokyo London  Paris Seattle  Paris  Other  0
#3  3  London Berlin  Paris   Paris Berlin London  0
#4  4 Seattle Berlin London   Tokyo  Paris Boston  1
```

---

A `tidyverse` approach using `gather`/`spread` would be

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(FP = +(!any(value[key %in% pred_cols] %in% value[key %in% obs_cols]))) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for the answer. what does the plus sign in front of apply() , from the first chunk,  or in front of any() - from the second chunk,  do?

Comment: @Molly That is used to convert logical (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) values to integer values (`1`/`0`). Check `+c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(FP = ifelse(Pred1 %in% Obs1|Pred2 %in% Obs2|Pred3 %in% Obs3|
                    Pred1 %in% Obs2|Pred2 %in% Obs1|Pred3 %in% Obs2|
                    Pred1 %in% Obs3|Pred2 %in% Obs3|Pred3 %in% Obs1, "0", "1"))
```

This is the most crude approach if the data is limited to only these 6 columns

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of ways to do this as has been shown by all the answers, you can use your original idea of `c(pred1, pred2, pred3) %in% c(obs1, obs2, obs3)` but you need to check for at least 1 `TRUE` hence summing and checking if there is `>0` TRUE is possible, hence,
Taking into account your comment for this to be `rowwise`, i will not group anything

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(FP = sum(c(Pred1, Pred2, Pred3) %in% c(Obs1, Obs2, Obs3)) > 0, # TRUE if at least 1 match
         FP = as.numeric(!FP)) # This turns TRUE -> FALSE -> 0 as required

     ID Pred1   Pred2  Pred3  Obs1    Obs2   Obs3      FP
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 Boston  Tokyo  London Boston  London Other      0
2     2 Tokyo   London Paris  Seattle Paris  Other      0
3     3 London  Berlin Paris  Paris   Berlin London     0
4     4 Seattle Berlin London Tokyo   Paris  Boston     1
```